# Are 赢 and 蠃 somwhow related?

Tags: characters

Does anyone knows how/if the wasp character 蠃 is related to win 赢 character?

Online searches came up empty.

Answer (score 1):

The two words were invented quite differently but had gradually approching similarities for unknown reasons.

[image][image]
蜾蠃也。从虫聲。

[image]

[image][image]
从贝，从贏，赢( yíng  )省声。贝，古货币，与财富买卖有关。本义:有余

[image]